# Google Geocode API - Echo specific details in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm using this script to get the geo-code information from Google but I don't know how to filter out just specifics such as Lat, Lon, Town, County. Here is my code (which I beleive will work under the new API-3?):

```
<?php
$address="LS1 7AS";
$result=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false" );
    $geocodedinfo=json_decode($result);

print_r($geocodedinfo);
?>
```

This prints out all of the information I need but as a block, I just want to have some of them so I can insert it into a table, for example:

```
$town = "town from result";
$county = "county from result";
$lat = "lat from result";
$lon = "lon from result";
```

Comment: Your output format is XML.But why you are decoding data using `json_decode()`.

Comment: @som I'm new to this and saw that this was the new way to do it for API-3. What is a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all You need to modify your API output format.Use output format `json` because you have already used `json_decode` function.

```
$address="LS1 7AS";
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false";
```

And you variables should look like :

```
$geocodedinfo=json_decode($result);
```

You have to check return status :

```
if($geocodedinfo->status == 'OK') {
     $country = $geocodeinfo->results[0]->address_components[3]->long_name;
     $town = $geocodeinfo->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name;
     $lat = $geocodeinfo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
     $lon = $geocodeinfo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to know what the code actually is inside the if statement

Comment: Sorry ? you have to check the status first to know if the webservice return a result or not...

Comment: @SebP What do you mean? Can you tell me if this script is Client side? I really need it to be converted of not, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: the script of @som if server side. If you want to do the same thing in client side you have to do something like :

    var json_obj = eval();
    if ( json_obj.status  ==== 'OK' ) {
        var country = json_obj.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
        ...
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$address="LS1 7AS";
$result = @file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false" );
if ($result === FALSE) {
    //manage exception from file_get_contents call
} else {
    $geocodedinfo = json_decode($result);
    if ($geocodedinfo->status == "OK") {
        $county = "";
        $town = "";
        foreach ($geocodedinfo->results[0]->address_components as $addrcomps) {
            if ( $addrcomps->types[0] == 'postal_town')
                $town = $addrcomps->long_name;
            if ( $addrcomps->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2')
                $county = $addrcomps->long_name;
        }
        $lat = $geocodedinfo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lon = $geocodedinfo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    }
}
```

Sometimes the file_get_contents function calls returns an exception. So you should use @ before call it.